# MySQL distributed database with mysql access to each node

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, distributed-database

I have task to implement particular database structure:

Multiple mysql servers with data using the same schema. Each server can see and edit only his particular part of data.

And

One master server with his own data that can run queries using data from all previously mentioned servers, but cannot edit them.

Example would be multiple hospitals with data of their patients and master server that can use combined data from all hospitals.

Previous system was written using mysql cluster, so i tried it naturally. I can create mysql cluster with multiple nodes and maybe even partition data so i can have particular set of data in particular node, but as far as i know i can't connect to single node using mysql, because it is already connected to cluster.

Can it be done with mysql cluster? Is there other framework that can do that easily?

Comment: Might find more luck on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use http://galeracluster.com/. You can perform updates on all slaves and every server has all data, but it might still meet your requirements.